# 'Unknown extension' in save function of PIL due to empty EXTENSION array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am rather new to python and have a problem with the `save` function of the Pillow fork of PIL.

With this minimal example

```
import Image

im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 30), "#ddd")
im.save("image.png")
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1667, in save
  raise KeyError(ext)  # unknown extension
KeyError: '.png'
```

The corresponding lines in the `save` function are

```
preinit()

[...]

try:
  format = EXTENSION[ext]
except KeyError:
  raise KeyError(ext)  # unknown extension
```

I looked at the `EXTENSION` array and detected that it is empty, although it should be initialized in `preinit()` by for example `from PIL import PngImagePlugin`. `PngImagePlugin.py` calls `Image.register_extension("PNG", ".png")`. Watching the array inside this function or inside `PngImagePlugin` it is indeed filled with file extensions.

Putting `print(EXTENSION)` right before the try-except-block however shows an empty `EXTENSION` array.

(Same issue with the `SAVE` array a few lines down in the `save` function.)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I recently upgraded from OpenSuse 13.1. to 13.2. It worked fine in 13.1 but not in 13.2.

Comment: This works for me. In your case, try using `im.save("image.png", format='PNG')` and see if that works for you.

Comment: This is not working either. The corresponding section is skipped in Image.py but then I have the same error with the `SAVE` array: `File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1674, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]  # unknown format
KeyError: 'PNG''`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to write this instead:

```py
from PIL import Image # Notice the 'from PIL' at the start of the line

im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 30), "#ddd")
im.save("image.png")
```